redirection operator now fails in cron job after migrating to cloud
I have a line like this on my cronjob:
22 9 * * 1-5 cd ~/execution/samples/Cpp/data_logger/; ./data_logger_static 127.0.0.1 $TWS_LIVE_PORT &> SPY-STK.csv

It worked great and wrote a bunch of data to a file called SPY-STK.csv.
However, I recently this to a remote server, and it has stopped working. The file is created, but it's simply empty. Same code everywhere, and I tried to keep the OS the same, too. No idea what to even check.

Old local machine OS: Ubuntu 22.04
New Remote machine OS: Ubuntu 23.10
Old bash version: GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
New remote machine bash: GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

The output I'm interested in is from the error output stream (i.e. std::cerr in c++).

the ~ is probably also a problem. In cron best to use absolute paths

The &> stdout+stderr redirection is a bashism - the default shell for cron jobs is /bin/sh which will interpret it as & (place job in background) and > (redirect stdout only).
So either use POSIX redirections
22 9 * * 1-5 ... "$TWS_LIVE_PORT" > SPY-STK.csv 2>&1

or set the cron shell to bash before the job entry
SHELL=/bin/bash
22 9 * * 1-5 ... "$TWS_LIVE_PORT" &> SPY-STK.csv

(Variable expansions like $TWS_LIVE_PORT should be double quoted in both sh and bash.)

Might be worth noting that /bin/sh is not actually a shell binary or an interpreter per-se but rather a file defined in the standards of filesystem hierarchy in Linux systems which is usually linked to a POSIX shell binary and that happened to be the dash shell on Ubuntu.
